# VBA check for value in a range

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I am trying to loop through a column and if cells = "what i'm lookng for" then do something.
I have this so far, where I'm off is in the if statement where I check for the "name":

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim wksDest             As Worksheet
Dim wksSource           As Worksheet

Dim rngSource           As Range

Dim name                 As String

Dim LastRow             As Long
Dim LastCol             As Long
Dim c                   As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wksSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With wksSource
LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For c = 16 To 20
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
Set rngSource = .Range(.Cells(5, 16), .Cells(LastRow, 16))
name = rngSource.Value

If name = "mark"
do something 
End If

Next c
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'MsgBox "Done!", vbExclamation

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use [AUTOFILTER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s) to achieve what you want...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK Chris
Maybe a bit of simplification is required but also a few assumptions.
It doesn't seem like LastCol is being used for anything - so let's assume this is the Column you want to loop through.
Your loop has fixed start and end values yet you are determining the LastRow - so let's assume you want to start from row 5 (in your code) and loop to the LastRow in the LastCol.
In order to determine LastCol you must have data in the row you are using to do this - so let's assume that there are values in row 1 in all columns up to column you want to loop say 16 (in your code).
If you want to (IF) test for a single (string) value in this case then you must arrange for your rngSource to be a single cell value.  You also don't need to assign this to a variable unless you need to use it again.
Finally, if you want to check for other values you may want to consider using a SELECT CASE structure in place of your IF THEN structure.
Have a look at the following and change my assumptions to meet your requirement - good luck.

```
Sub test()

Dim wksDest             As Worksheet
Dim wksSource           As Worksheet

Dim rngSource           As Range

Dim name                 As String

Dim LastRow             As Long
Dim LastCol             As Long
Dim c                   As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wksSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With wksSource
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, LastCol).End(xlUp).Row

        FirstRow = 5
            For c = FirstRow To LastRow
                If .Range(.Cells(c, LastCol), .Cells(c, LastCol)).Value = "Mark" Then
                    MsgBox ("do something")
                End If
            Next c
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Yes a case statement is better for what I'm doing, since it's multiple values that I'm checking. "rngSource" is not used anymore, in your revision, so I'm taking it out. Now I just have to figure out what I want it to do when in each check.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do that with one line.

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match(ValueToSearchFor, RangeToSearchIn, 0)) Then
'The value found in the given range
End If
```

**Example:**
Search for "Canada" in column C of sheet named "Country"

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match("Canada", Sheets("Country").Range("C:C"), 0)) Then
   'The value found in the given range
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass value to find and Column where value need to be checked. It will return row num if its found else return 0.

```
Function checkForValue(FindString As String,ColumnToCheck as String) As Long
        SheetLastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).row
         With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$" & ColumnToCheck & "$1:$" & ColumnToCheck & "$" & CStr(SheetLastRow) ) 
                Set rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                lookat:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
                If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                    checkForValue = rng.row 'return row its found
                    'write code you want.                   
                Else
                    checkForValue = 0
                End If
            End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried Hari's suggestion, but Application.Match works weird on range names (not recognizing them...)

Changed to: WorksheetFunction.Match(... 
It works, but when value is not present A runtime ERROR jumps before IsError(...) is evaluated.
So I had to write a simple -no looping- solution:

```
dim Index as Long

Index = -1
On Error Resume Next
  Index = WorksheetFunction.Match(Target,Range("Edificios"), 0) 'look for Target value in range named: Edificios
On Error GoTo 0
If Index > 0 Then
    ' code for existing value found in Range @ Index row
End If
```

Remeber Excel functions first index = 1 (no zero based)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing what you really want to do is loop through your range `rngSource`. So try

```
Set rngSource = .Range(.Cells(5, 16), .Cells(LastRow, 16))
for myCell in rngSource
  if myCell.Value = "mark" then
    do something
  end if
next myCell
```